# How to add a line space before/after a letter/word in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to add a line break after a word in replace mode in Notepad++?

I need to turn lots of text like this:

```
[a]
1
2
3
[b]
1
2
3
[c]
1
2
3
[d]
1
2
3
```

into this:

```
[a]
1
2
3

[b]
1
2
3

[c]
1
2
3

[d]
1
2
3
```

What I am planning to do is `ctrl+H` > enter `"]"` in `Find what:` > `] + the line break representative` in `Replace with:` > `Replace all`

Though I'm not sure if there is. I hope there is a workaround since I need to this for thousands of lines of texts and codes.

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Do you mean like this? Find what: `(?=\R\[)` and replace with `]\n` https://regex101.com/r/ByQEa0/1

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead asserting what is on the right is a newline followed by a `[`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ByQEa0/1)

**Find what:**

```
(?=\R\[)
```

Or a more specific pattern matching a digit before and opening till closing parenthesis on the new line:

```
(?<=\d)(?=\R\[[^]\[]*\])
```

**Replace with:**

```
\n
```

[image]

Comment: wow this is really helpful! Will definitely add this on my notes and probably learn more about regex. Thank you!